# aws elastic beanstalk worker environment in degraded state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a worker environment associated with my web app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have a scheduled task defined in a `cron.yaml` file.

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "Import from source"
   url: "/import"
   schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
```

The POST /import exists and I can curl it from the EC2 host.

I get errors at deploy time:

```
worker-production - ERROR: Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
worker-production - ERROR: [Instance: i-01e793471e4fc59de] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
worker-production - INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
worker-production - ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-01e793471e4fc59de'. Aborting the operation.
worker-production - ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
worker-production - ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

And when inspecting via `eb logs` I see the following error:

```
2023-04-17T19:39:13Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.4 (2022-03-18)
2023-04-17T19:39:13Z schedule-parser: Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from file /var/app/current/cron.yaml .
2023-04-17T19:39:13Z init: Requested resource not found (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ResourceNotFoundException)
        at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_simple_attributes.rb:112:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.632/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:81:in `update_registration'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:19:in `verify_table'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:37:in `initialize'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `new'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `create'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:259:in `leader_election_daemon'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:47:in `new'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:47:in `initialize'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `new'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `start'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm wondering how I might overcome this to get the environment back to a healthy state and get my scheduled tasks to run.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time accepting this as "the answer" but what seems to have made the error go away was changing from a `t3.micro` to a `t3.small` instance type via my env.yaml file.

```
OptionSettings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    InstanceType: t3.small
    EC2KeyName: aws-eb
```

Perhaps the additional resources made aws-sqsd happy, or perhaps just rebuilding the environment from a new EC2 instance is what did the trick.

I'm certainly happy that I'm now unblocked, but will certainly accept other answers from anyone that's managed to find a true root cause.